Why would a commodore leak coolant and wiper fluid at the same time
The car also just got some issues with the window and battery fixed and now it is leaking coolant and wiper fluid
It may have been doing this for a while, as there are red coolant stains in the driveway
Also, we park in a driveway with a large slope, could this be causing issues?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!


Also, we park in a driveway with a large slope, could this be causing issues?

No.
Even if you park your car upside down (unlikely), coolant shouldn't leak assuming your radiator cap is tight. The cooling system is a pressurized one. Try to open the cap when it's hot and you see what I mean. Thus, it has to hold the pressure no matter which direction of the car is up. Gentle slope or even parking the car upside down doesn't cause any coolant leaks.
The leak must happen due to some broken hose, gasket or even if you're unlucky a broken radiator.
Wiper fluid leaks are possible too, unlikely that they are related to the coolant leaks except by age. Hoses and gaskets tend to have a finite lifetime and multiple independent hoses/gaskets can fail at approximately the same age in different systems of the car.

I was more thinking whether the stress of everything being pulled to the front potentially causing damage over time

Oh no, the increase of hydrostatic pressure when the car is not on a level ground is extremely minor. Yes, maybe the hydrostatic pressure may increase by 1% or so, but then again, the cooling system is a pressurized one, and experiences pressures far greater than the hydrostatic pressure when it's hot. No way is a non-level ground going to cause leaks.

I was more thinking about plastic creeping and screw threads cracking

Maybe the weight of the components caused screws and pipes to crack?

Insignificant compared to all the other forces acting on the coolant system.
